# How to fix 'Invalid URL' while creating embedded Kafka in Spring test

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am trying to build a test for a piece of code that send data to a Kafka topic, I've been reading an example which looks pretty straightforward, however when I try to run the test, it fails throwing this error: 'Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: spring.embedded.kafka.brokers'

The URL 'spring.embedded.kafka.brokers' I've got it from the docs, I can't find right now the link source though. This is what I have tried so far:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@TestPropertySource({"classpath:application-test.properties"})
public class PublishCustomerServiceImplTest {

    private String bootstrapServers = "spring.embedded.kafka.brokers";

    private static final String TOPIC = "TopicName";

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner");
        return props;
    }

    public ProducerFactory<String, CustomerPublishRequest> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    public KafkaTemplate<String, CustomerPublishRequest> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, TOPIC);

    @Test
    public void publishCustomerTest() throws Exception {

        KafkaTemplate<String, CustomerPublishRequest> kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate();

        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, CustomerPublishRequest>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, CustomerRequestDummy.getCustomer());
        SendResult<String, CustomerPublishRequest> sendResult = future.get();
        long offset = sendResult.getRecordMetadata().offset();

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear this is `spring.embedded.kafka.brokers` invalid bootstrap-server URL, get it from `EmbeddedKafkaRule`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@TestPropertySource({"classpath:application-test.properties"})
public class PublishCustomerServiceImplTest {

private static final String TOPIC = "TopicName";

 @ClassRule
public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, TOPIC);

public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner");
    return props;
}

public ProducerFactory<String, CustomerPublishRequest> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
}

public KafkaTemplate<String, CustomerPublishRequest> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

@Test
public void publishCustomerTest() throws Exception {

    KafkaTemplate<String, CustomerPublishRequest> kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate();

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, CustomerPublishRequest>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, CustomerRequestDummy.getCustomer());
    SendResult<String, CustomerPublishRequest> sendResult = future.get();
    long offset = sendResult.getRecordMetadata().offset();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem and then fixed it by overriding two following properties,

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}",
                                  "spring.kafka.admin.properties.bootstrap.servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}"})
```